# Executing a command with string doesn't work in powershell

Tags: powershell

This is my code and it doesn't work:

```
$brisanje=dat.txt, dat2.txt
Remove-Item $brisanje
```

The error that I get here is

Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\stefan\Desktop\brisanjedat\dat.txt, dat2.txt' because it does not exist.

But when I write it like this it works like a charm:

```
Remove-Item dat.txt, dat2.txt
```

I've been stuck with this problem for hours, any solutions?

Comment: `$brisanje="dat.txt","dat2.txt"`

Comment: thank you, it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PowerShell parser has [two modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), depending on context.

When in an *argument mode* context (like in the case of `Remove-Item dat.txt,dat2.txt`), it treats the bare words as a list of expandable strings.

In *expression mode* (the default), a bare word at the start of an expression is treated like a command and powershell will attempt to resolve it, which is why you see the error.

Use quotes to make sure the parser knows you mean `dat1.txt,dat2.txt` to be a string array:

```
$brisanje="dat.txt","dat2.txt"
```

See the output from `Get-Help about_Parsing` for more information

Answer (score 1):

It's also a good idea to use dot (.) sourcing in your code too.
Shells and Scripts have different scopes, and when you dot source variables you combine the two. I dot source everything, especially if I'm using it over and over again or in different environments.

`cd C:\Users\stefan\Desktop\brisanjedat\ 
$brisanje= ".\dat.txt",".\dat2.txt"
Remove-Item $brisanje`